# Gnuplot histogram gap does nothing

Tags: gnuplot, histogram, spacing

I have a gnuplot script which plots a histogram. I used the following syntax:

```
set style data histogram
set style histogram cluster gap 2
set style fill solid

set logscale y

rgb(r,g,b) = int(r)*65536 + int(g)*256 + int(b)

plot 'histogram_data' using (column(0)):2:(0.5):(rgb($3,$4,$5)):xticlabels(1) w boxes notitle lc rgb variable
```

What the last line does is: using column 1 as x labels, column 2 as the height of the histogram bars, 0.5 as box width, and columns 3, 4 and 5 as the rgb values to colour the bars.

Now, the problem is that modifying the gap parameter in line 2 does not change in any way the spacing between bars, even though as far as I understand that is the correct way to adjust such spacing. I am using gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 4.

Comment: Correct, the `gap` does nothing, because you use the `boxes` potting style instead of `histogram`.

Comment: I see, that is a very good thing to know. But now if I change `boxes` to `histogram` it outputs `Too many using specs for this style`. I imagine this is due to the fact that I am specifying colours, labels and whatnot in the plot line. How can I adjust the space between the bars using boxes? Or, alternatively, how can I specify xticlabels and dynamic colours using histogram?

Comment: You must not give the x-coordinates for the `histogram` style. And you are right, using variable colours doesn't work with histograms either, and it also doesn't make sense. So, using boxes is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this with boxes, though I do not consider it very clean:

```
plot 'histogram_data' u (column(0)*2+1):2 w boxes notitle lc rgb 'white',\
     'histogram_data' u (column(0)*2):2:(rgb($3,$4,$5)):xticlabels(1) w boxes notitle lc rgb variable;
```

This command is plotting all the data of the main plot on even slots and a white box on odd slots. So the first line in the plot command is plotting the gaps between every box of the plot (the width of these gaps can be specified using the `boxwidth` property I think but I haven't tested this), while the second line is drawing the actual plot.

I could not find a way to do this with the `histogram` plotting style, keeping the variable colours specified in the data file.

Comment: Why don't you just use `set boxwidth 0.66 relative; plot "histogram_data" using 0:2:(rgb($3,$4,$5)):xticlabels(1) with boxes notitle lc rgb var`?

Comment: Because I have many labels on the x axis and I need to use a large enough font to represent them all, so I really need quite a lot of space between every two boxes.

Comment: But that's a different problem. My example was only to show how you can get some white gap between two boxes. If your labels overlap, you'll have that problem in any case. Try rotating the labels with `set xtics rotate by 90 right`.

Comment: My labels are already rotated by 90 degrees. The problem is that I need quite a large font so these label overlap anyway. Plotting a new box (without label, of course) in between every couple of boxes prevents rotated labels from overlapping.